# Create table with the week numbers of the last 6 months, with their respective month and year. SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get a table that contains the week number of the last 6 months. I found some code in github, and I modified it to accomplish my goal.

This what I have:

```
-- choosing date to start with
DECLARE @start_date DATE = DATEADD(MONTH, -6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

SELECT DISTINCT  
    DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(DAY, Number, @start_date)) AS week_number, 
    DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(DAY, Number, @start_date)) AS year, --adding year number to order by year
    DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(DAY, Number, @start_date)) AS month_number
FROM  
    master..spt_values 
WHERE 
    Type = 'P'
    AND DATEADD(DAY, Number, @start_date) <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
    AND DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(DAY, Number, @start_date)) > 2019
```

-- 2019 only used to show the info from 2020 and above, because I don't want the week number of 2019 or below

I get this result :

[result of the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnUza.png)

The problem is that week 5 is repeated because apparently that week number is between 2 different months, but I just want to keep one of the results no matter the month or year, I want the week number to appear just once.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, use `GROUP BY` in your query and pick either the `MAX` or `MIN` value of `month_number` for each `year` and `week_number`.  Here's an example, but I'm using a recursive CTE rather than that clunky query that relies on a table that has a limited number of numbers in it.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        @start_date AS [date],
        DATEPART(WEEK, @start_date) AS week_number, 
        DATEPART(YEAR, @start_date) AS [year],
        DATEPART(MONTH, @start_date) AS month_number
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        DATEADD(DAY, 1, [date]) AS [date],
        DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(DAY, 1, [date])) AS week_number, 
        DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(DAY, 1, [date])) AS [year],
        DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(DAY, 1, [date])) AS month_number
    FROM
        cte
    WHERE
        [date] <= GETDATE())
SELECT
    [year],
    MAX(month_number) AS month_number,
    week_number
FROM
    cte
WHERE
    [year] > 2019
GROUP BY
    [year],
    week_number
ORDER BY
    1, 2, 3 OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

I get these results:

```
year    month_number    week_number
2020    1               1
2020    1               2
2020    1               3
2020    1               4
2020    2               5
2020    2               6
2020    2               7
2020    2               8
2020    2               9
2020    3               10
2020    3               11
2020    3               12
2020    3               13
2020    3               14
```

If I chose `MIN` instead of `MAX` I would get the same results, but week 5 would be assigned to month 1.

Comment: @ignacio.ambia, it's good that you found a useful answer. Please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the grey check mark to the left. It rewards the person who answered with some reputation points, and you get some, too.

Comment: using spt_values or a tally table would be typically advisable vs the recursive cte.